# Can't run a SQL Script own MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed MySQL server and MySQL Workbench on Mac OS Monterey. I am trying to run a .sql file on Workbench, it gives me this error message:"ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe in position 2380: ordinal not in range(128)." Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you try to open your SQL file using a text editor and convert it to UTF8 and then open it on MySQL Workbench to see if it solves the issue? It looks like the file's encoding is not correct or there are invalid chars.

Comment: Thanks @endo64. I clicked on File -> open script-> Run Script and it solved the issue.  Earlier I went directly File-Run Script -then upload from Desktop and it didn't run. Now resolved.

Comment: Good to hear that your issue is resolved, you can add your resolution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug report related to the same error as yours here:-
[bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60276)

But in your case since ordinal is not in range , you should try to covert your SQL file to any other encoding schemes like UTF8 . You can do that using these steps:-
[see here](https://hostlantern.com/clients/knowledgebase/1121/How-to-save-an-.sql-file-with-UTF-8-encoding.html)

After this try to open the script in MySql Workbench , issue must be resolved .